# Turkish e-Visa Validity if passport gets stolen or you get a new

Tags: turkey, e-visas

I issued myself a Turkish e-visa as I was travelling to the united kingdom and I was eligible to get e-visa as a Pakistani citizen, but due to some situation I wasn't able to use that visa and now my passport got lost and I applied for a new UK Visa which I will get shortly.

Will my e-visa for turkey will be valid or do I have to get the new e-visa?

Answer (score 1):

Syed, Your e-visa was linked to your old passport, so you will have to get a new visa for Turkey. I haven't had this problem in Turkey before, but I had a similar situation with an Australian visa.